# How to separate an array and store it in a new array?

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcpy

What I want to do is: The user inputs a string with commas; for example: `123456,44,55,,66`

and I want to separate it and store in a new array without the commas; for example:

```
m[0][]={123456}, m[1][]={44}, m[2][]={55}, m[3][]={}, m[4][]={66}
```

`123456` is the student ID number, `44` is the mark for 1st module, `55` is the mark for 2nd module, `NULL` means that the student didn't take that 3rd module, and `66` is the mark for 4th module.

How can I exactly do that? What I know is that by detecting double commas, it means the student didn't take that 3rd module.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void copystring(char m[],char temp[]);

main()
{
    char temp[10000];
    char m[10000][10000];
    gets(temp);
    copystring(m,temp);
    printf("%s\n",m);           
    return 0;
}

void copystring(char m[],char temp[])
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (j=0;j<(strlen(temp));j++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<(strlen(temp));i++)
        {
            if (temp[i]!=*(",")&&temp[i]!=*(" "))
            {
                m[j][i]=temp[i];
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your call to `copystring(char **, char *)` is not defined.

Comment: Where are you stuck? what are you missing - please you be specific?

Comment: Don't use [gets()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Comment: Smac89,sorry but I don't really know how to define it correctly.
NiRR,sorry but I am not sure whether there is a problem in my codes and I don't know how to correct it. Could you please help me to check on it?

Comment: moeCake,what should I use?

Comment: Adding to @moeCake : Didn't you get warning: `gets() is dangerous, Use fgets() instead`

Comment: That's probably the first time I see someone write `*(",")` in C. You need to read more basic tutorial material on the language. A single character constant should be written as `','` (single quotes, not double).

Comment: @unwind : Also, to mention more clearly, Use `temp[i]!= ','` instead of `temp[i]!=*(",")`. He might take it as `temp[i]!=*(',')`.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using arrays to store a single element like m[1][]={44}, why not m[1]=44 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited my code so that you can understand how to declare a function prototype containing 2D array as parameter. Also use fgets() instead of gets(). The function returns the number of marks read , i.e. an integer. I think this might help. Run the code and look on the man pages or google to understand fgets() better.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 1000
int stringcopy(char m[][SIZE],char temp[]);
main()
{
        char temp[SIZE],m[100][SIZE];
        fgets(temp,SIZE,stdin);
        int num=stringcopy(m,temp);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<num;++i)
                printf("%s\n",m[i]);
        return 0;
}
int stringcopy(char m[][SIZE],char temp[]) {
        int len=strlen(temp);
        int i,j=0,k=0;
        for(i=0;i<len;++i) {
                if(temp[i]!=',')
                        m[j][k++]=temp[i];
                else {
                        m[j][k]='\0';
                        ++j;
                        k=0;
                }
        }
        m[j][k-1]='\0';
        return j+1;
}
```

Comment: It didn't works. =(
I want to make it like
m[0][]={123456},m[1][]={44},m[2][]={55},m[3][]={},m[4][]={66}.

Comment: I ran the above code and got thefollowin output :

123456
44
55

66

It means that m[0] ={123456} , m[1]={44} , m[2] = {55} and m[3]= {} and m[4] = {66} . Doesn't it suffice your problem ??

Comment: I got this
warning:arithmetic on pointer to an incomplete type
m[j][k++]=temp[i]

Comment: Actually in your main function , you are passing m (a 2d array) to copystring (which takes 1d array) , as you defined the prototype wrong. Just copy and paste my whole program and run it. Then you will understand the problem in your code.

Comment: Can you please teach how should I defined the prototype correctly. I run your program, the last for loop only print out m[0], if print it one by one, it works.
printf("%s\n",m[0]);
printf("%s\n",m[1]); and so on...

Comment: @user3118123- I have edited my code to include function prototypes. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot! just want to ask why must it be m[100][SIZE], I try m[SIZE][SIZE] but the program cannot runs. How is this possible?

Comment: @user3118123- its not at all compulsory.SIZE only bounds the number of marks you can hold and you can keep it whatever you want. Infact m[SIZE][SIZE] runs just fine on my machine. Can u tell what error do you get ?

Comment: I can't tell from my compiler. When I run my program, the message "xxx.c has just stopped working" popped out. I use C-Free 4.0

Comment: Oh. Try reducing the size. It will work. It may be because of the array of dimensions 1000*1000 .

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve your problem in different steps,

The first step is to check how many tokens you have in your input string to be able to allocate enough space to store an array of tokens.

Then you should extract the tokens of the input strings in your tokens string array. To extract the tokens from your input string, you can use the `strtok` function from `<string.h>`.

Finally you can use your tokens however you want, like converting them to `long` in your case.

EDIT: given the requirements, here is a small implementation of what you could do. I don't check the returns of the malloc, you maybe should do it.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i;

    char* input_string = /* your input string for somewhere */;

    char** tokens;
    int tokens_count = 0;
    char* input_ptr = input_string;

    char* tmp_token;
    size_t tmp_token_length;

    // count the occurences of your separtor to have the number of elements
    for(; input_ptr[tokens_count]; input_ptr[tokens_count] == ',' ? tokens_count++ : input_ptr++);

    if(tokens_count == 0) {
        // no tokens found, what do you want to do here ?
    }
    else {
        // build our tokens array
        tokens = malloc(sizeof(*tokens) * tokens_count);
        i = 0;

        tmp_token = strtok(input_string, ',');
        while(tmp_token != NULL) {
            tmp_token_length = strlen(tmp_token);

            if(tmp_token_length != 0) {
                tokens[i] = malloc(tmp_token_length);
                strcpy(tokens[i], tmp_token);
            }
            else {
                tokens[i] = NULL;
            }

            i++;
            tmp_token = strtok(input_string, ',');
        }

        // populate your array of arrays of integers
        long** m = malloc(sizeof(long*) * tokens_count);

        for(i=0; i<tokens_count; i++) {
            char* tmp_token = tokens[i];

            if(tmp_token == NULL) {
                m[i] = NULL;
            }
            else {
                m[i] = malloc(sizeof(long));
                m[i][0] = strtol(tmp_token, NULL, 10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, you should probably change your data structure by using structures instead of a massive array.

Comment: Well I think you want to say "converting", "casting" string to integer is not possible. ;-)

Comment: Yes these functions convert string to integer, casting is the term use to denote data type change done by using *cast* operator.

Comment: that's being picky, but true it is indeed converting.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (j=0;j<(strlen(temp));j++)
{
    for (i=0;i<(strlen(temp));i++)
    {
        if (temp[i]!=(',')&&temp[i]!=(' '))
        {
            m[j][i]=temp[i];
        }   
        else{
            m[j][i]='\0';break;// must end a string with null character.
        }
    }
}
```

and for priting use

```
printf("%s",m[0]);// make a loop for it
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `scanf` for getting input, your `copystring` function seems fine; but if there is a problem then debug it to see what the problem is.

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the beginning of the function then run in debug mode. Which compiler do you use?

Answer (score -1):

You can read entire string using `fgets`, or `scanf` and then use `strtok(string, ",")` to get substrings between commas.

To detect if student has missed some entry, there are many ways, few of them are:

1) Check no. of sub-strings  you get before `strtok` returns `NULL`.
2) You can search for substring `,,` using `strstr` in the input string.

Comment: To the user who downvoted: I have added more to my answer, please review it.

Comment: can you please show me the entire codes? thanks. I don't really understand how to use strtok and strstr

Comment: It is not that difficult, just refer to [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/), here you can find help for `strstr` also. Giving you entire codes will not help unless you know their purpose.